# How do you query OWL Annotations

Tags: search, rdf, owl

I am searching for the method/tool/syntax to query annotations in an RDF/OWL ontology.

The query engines I have found search classes, properties, individuals, but I have not found one that will search based on the value for example DC:Description

Answer (score 1):

With SPARQL, you should be able to query annotations via the properties you're interested in, for example:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?x ?desc {
  ?x dc:description ?desc .
}
```

This method could also be used to retrieve all instances with a particular annotation value, such as:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?x {
  ?x dc:description "some description string" .
}
```

Or, you could even try to match based on some REGEX:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?x {
  ?x dc:description ?desc .
  FILTER REGEX(STR(?desc), "^Some regex") .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a programmtic tool and the ontology is OWL you can use the Manchester OWL API:

```
OWLClass classA = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("http://your/url/here#ClassA"));
OWLAnnotationProperty dcProperty = factory.getOWLAnnotationProperty(IRI.create("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description"));

for (OWLAnnotation annotation : classA.getAnnotations(ontology, dcProperty)) {
OWLLiteral literal = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
String literalString = literal.getLiteral()
                }
```

That will get you the value of that particular property. "factory" here is an instance of OWLDataFactory.

Hope that helps a little!